# How to abbreviate a string in R

Tags: r, stringr

I need to abbreviate department names by their first character, so  that `strDept="Department of Justice"` becomes `strDeptAbbr = "DoJ".`

How can I abbreviate a string using `stringr`?
Thank you

Comment: I use `str_remove_all(full_names, "(?<!^|[:space:]).")`. The regex matches all characters that are not preceded by the start of the string or a space, so they're removed, and only the first letter of each word, including the first word, remains.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With `base R`, you can do:

```
abbreviate("Department of Justice", 1, named = FALSE)

[1] "DoJ"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
library(stringr)
x="Department of Justice"
new_list=strsplit(x, " ")
str_sub(as.list(new_list[[1]]),1,1)
```

The previous answer by @tmfmnk is much better in my opinion.

**Edit:**

As @Lyngbakr pointed out, the following code will yield the final result requested:

```
paste(str_sub(as.list(new_list[[1]]),1,1), collapse = "")
```

Comment: To get the desired result, I think you'd need to add a call to `paste` like this `paste(str_sub(as.list(new_list[[1]]),1,1), collapse = "")`, which gives `"DoJ"`. Otherwise, you get `"D" "o" "J"`.

Comment: Yes. That would give the final answer OP requested. Thanks a lot for pointing this out. @Lyngbakr . I will add this line to the above code.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative  but overly "complicated" `base` solution:

```
paste(unlist(lapply(strsplit(strDept," "),function(x) substring(x,1,1))),collapse = "")
#[1] "DoJ"
```

You can avoid `lapply` as suggested by @Lyngbakr:

```
 paste(substring(unlist(strsplit(strDept," ")), 1, 1), 
       collapse = "")
[1] "DoJ"
```

If you want to stick with `stringr`:

```
paste(substring(stringr::str_split(strDept, pattern = " ", simplify = TRUE), 1, 1), collapse = "")
```

Comment: You can avoid `lapply` and `unlist` like this: `paste(substring(str_split(strDept, pattern = " ", simplify = TRUE), 1, 1), collapse = "")`

Comment: Thanks, edited to add this option.

Answer (score 2):

I really like @tmfmnk solution, however if you want to stick to stringr you could use this:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
x = "Department of Justice"
x %>% 
  str_split(pattern = " ") %>%
  map(str_trunc, 1, ellipsis = "") %>%
  map(str_c, collapse="") %>%
  flatten_chr()

[1] "DoJ"
```